# Error while installing python package: llama-cpp-python

Tags: python, llama, llama-cpp-python

I am using Llama to create an application. Previously I used openai but am looking for a free alternative. Based on my limited research, this library provides openai-like api access making it quite easy to add into my prexisting code. However this library has errors while downloading. I tried installing cmake which did not help.

```
Building wheels for collected packages: llama-cpp-python
  Building wheel for llama-cpp-python (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for llama-cpp-python (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [20 lines of output]
      *** scikit-build-core 0.5.1 using CMake 3.27.7 (wheel)
      *** Configuring CMake...
      2023-10-10 21:23:02,749 - scikit_build_core - WARNING - Can't find a Python library, got libdir=None, ldlibrary=None, multiarch=None, masd=None
      loading initial cache file C:\Users\ARUSHM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpf1bzj6ul\build\CMakeInit.txt
      -- Building for: NMake Makefiles
      CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3 (project):
        Running

         'nmake' '-?'

        failed with:

         The system cannot find the file specified


      CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
      CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
      -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

      *** CMake configuration failed
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for llama-cpp-python
Failed to build llama-cpp-python
ERROR: Could not build wheels for llama-cpp-python, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Although not directly related to this question, these are other questions I am unable to get answers for:

1. Does this library use Llama or Llama 2?
2. Will this be secure on a Python Flask Application?

Comment: To answer your first (1.) question:  this library wraps llama.cpp (https://github.com/ggerganov/llama.cpp), which supports a variety of models including both Llama and Llama 2.  You can specify the model, including competitors of Llama like Mistral.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to install the desktop c++ block with visual studio to get cmake properly installed.Open the Visual Studio Installer and click Modify, then check Desktop development with C++ and click Modify to start the install.  I also recommend the Windows 10 SDK.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/cmake-projects-in-visual-studio?view=msvc-170
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-sdk/
After that, !pip install llama-cpp-python should build just fine.

Comment: Just in case you don't have VS installer, you can find it with `Download Build Tools` from https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/. For me installing from `Workloads` point `Desktop development with C++` was enough.

Comment: I already have vs code installed. Will this still work? I run Windows btw, and I've had trouble running wsl and vms.

Comment: @hehe vs code and vs are different projects

Comment: this doesn't work for me

Answer (score 2):

For this error message

```
      CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
      CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
```

The `gcc` and `g++` are NOT installed, and the version of GCC should be over `gcc 11` per this [issue](https://github.com/imartinez/privateGPT/issues/445)

---

- Install `gcc` and `g++` under ubuntu

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
sudo apt update
sudo apt install gcc-11 g++-11
```

- Install `gcc` and `g++` under centos

```
yum install scl-utils 
yum install centos-release-scl
# find devtoolset-11
yum list all --enablerepo='centos-sclo-rh' | grep "devtoolset"

yum install -y devtoolset-11-toolchain
```

- Install `gcc` and `g++` under Amamzon Linux 2023

```
sudo dnf install gcc
sudo dnf install g++
```

Comment: I am on Windows. Also I have both gcc and g++ installed and on PATH