# ERROR: Could not build wheels for llama-cpp-python, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based project

Tags: llamacpp

While installing llama-cpp-python on VS Code i am getting an error

```
          4 Warning(s)
          257 Error(s)

      Time Elapsed 00:00:02.56


      *** CMake build failed
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for llama-cpp-python
Failed to build llama-cpp-python
ERROR: Could not build wheels for llama-cpp-python, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based project
```

I tried to install this library using pip but was always getting this error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error while installing python package: llama-cpp-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77267346/error-while-installing-python-package-llama-cpp-python)

Answer (score 0):

The "Microsoft C++ Build Tools" can be downloaded and installed from the official Visual Studio website. The actions you can do are as follows:

Check out the Visual C++ Build Tools at https://visualstudio.microsoft.com.

There need to be a "Download" button for the Visual Studio Build Tools on the website. Press it to start the download.

Installing the Microsoft C++ Build Tools requires running the installer and following the prompts after the download is finished.

Don't forget to pick the C++ development-related components throughout the installation procedure. Choosing the "C++ build tools" and any necessary libraries or packages is usually part of this.